# Help on Tab Layout example

Tags: android, eclipse

New bee to Android, I need help on creating tabs.

I am following the example stated in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

When I run the application, I am not seeing any tabs but only Songs tab.

I am not able to figure out how to resolve this.

Below code is added under AndriodManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.TabWidget.AlbumsActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
    <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.TabWidget.AlbumsActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SongsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.TabWidget.AlbumsActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your TabWidget implementation (Java code where you create the tabs). Also note that this manifest is wrong, you are using the same Intent filters for all three activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it look something like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SongsActivity"/>
</application>
```

This part:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

is for the entry part of your app.

Comment: click the tick on the left if the answer satisfies your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is a very simple example for tab-layout:

[Andorid Tab-Layout with icons](http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/Android-Tab-Layout-with-icons-QID1296480.aspx)